# How to modify CSV file prior to import into mySQL to allow for commas in data

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I am hoping there is a fix that does not involved adding PHP code or modifying mySQL. I need to import a CSV file . Whenever there is a comma in one of the names (ex: ABC Company, Inc.) it does not import the row. Beside this the import function works great.

I tried to modify the CSV file prior to import by surrounding the comma with "" as well as the name "ABC Company, Inc." but nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Ask the provider of the CSV file to give you a valid one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: You need to have a valid CSV file before you can import it. Why not throw it into a CSV-capable program like Excel, fix it up, and export it from there?

Comment: What are you using to import? PhpMyadmin?

Comment: 1) The CSV file is proper. It does require some of the data to have commas. 2) Excel is not option. 3)I use my custom made CMS to do the import.

Comment: 123 Company yes no  yes
456 Company, Inc. yes no  yes
The second scenario is causing the issue and removing the commas is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: What is your delimiter for columns?

Answer (score 0):

Create the csv with Quoted Identifiers.  Otherwise there is no way to tell a comma delimiter from a comma in a text field.

Either that or pick a delimiter that is not in any of the fields such as a "|" character or tab.

Comment: Do you mean make it ABC Company"," Inc. ? I tried this and it does not work still. About your second option, do you mean I can change the comma delimiter to being another character like "|" ?

Comment: Once the file is created there is nothing you can do aside from manually examining every record that might have an extra comma.  The best way to deal with it is to have it exported in a way that can be imported successfully.  A file with quoted identifiers would look like ...,"ABC Company, Inc.",... and the field would import properly.